# How to output modelform errors in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I trigger the opposite of is_valid()? This is how I have done it so far:

```
def post(self, request):
        user_form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        second_form = self.second_form_class(request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and second_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        invite = second_form.save(commit=False)

        username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
        code = second_form.cleaned_data['code']

        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('main:welcome')
```

I want to check if this is true, but I don't know how to implement it in my generic view:

```
the_invite = Invites.objects.filter(code=code)

if the_invite.exists():
    the_invite.delete()
else:
    second_form.add_error()
```

I want to simply output like this error message with for example: "You entered the wrong code": [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCymC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to simply output like this error message with for example: "You entered the wrong code""

Well, you can add errors to form like this:

```
form._errors = ErrorDict()
errors = form._errors.setdefault('[name of the field that failed verification]', ErrorList())
errors.append('[Your error message]')
```

And then return this form back to user.

Answer (score 0):

When form is invalid, you need to send it to template and render:

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

Comment: Yeah, but as soon as I enter a value in the second_form for example it is True even if the object is not in the database. How could I make a check for that?

Comment: The form you want errors you need to pass it to tamplate and render its errors. What form is your `request.POST` comming from?